# Digital Pen to programming code

Tags: digital-pen

Is there anyway we can write programming code instead of typing to use digital pen? I want this so that I can write, compile and run from the editor.

I have looked at some demos in youtube as well in advertisements, not sure which supports this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I would be highly skeptical of this working well. There is just not a lot of difference between a `{` and a `(` and I can't even get it close enough for humans to recognize most of the time on my whiteboard. When writing text, readers are relatively forgiving (notwithstanding the occasional flame war over a typo on the Internet). In programming these differences matter a lot and even if you found one you liked the interface for, the recognition probably isn't going to be accurate enough to be worth it.

Still, I'm expecting that you'll want an answer. Luckily, you probably already have the most popular Windows program to do this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/convert-your-handwritten-notes-to-text-by-using-windows-journal

If that works for you then use it. If it isn't working for you because you don't like the interface then look for something you do like or make your own using the [the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749012(v=vs.110).aspx) for handwriting recognition. If it doesn't work because you don't like the fact it is getting things wrong then I doubt there is going to be one you like because nearly all of them use the same API. Even if some don't and are better, I highly doubt any are good enough for me to use myself for this purpose.